# Deleting linux swap

Tags: gnome, swap

I deleted `linux swap` on my disk.

After removing `swap`, pc is starting up slowly.

Does lack of `Linux swap` can cause it?

Comment: use _nano_ text editor, like this `sudo nano /etc/fstab`. Then add a `#` to the _swap file_ entry, then reboot. AFAIK it's a __bad idea__ to remove swap

Comment: how can i add again

Comment: `# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
# UUID=e0ca0a52-fd55-459f-820a-be3531e21800 none            swap    sw              0       0` this my swap commented out. Do you know how to use _nano_? Please note the `#`s are on separate lines not same line as seen here.

Comment: To add swap do that from `gprated`.  Please post the result of `sudo lsblk -i` in your question. Let me see where your swap was...

Comment: @George I think you meant `gparted`

Comment: @NickWeinberg, yes meant `gprated`...

Comment: @George No, you meant `gparted` :)

Comment: @NickWeinberg, What is going on today, ya `gparted` I meant ;).

Comment: @George Depending on how much RAM you have, and how much you typically use, removing swap is a valid option.  I have 2 systems without swap, an 8GB system and a 16GB system.  I've never come near using even half my RAM and swap was never used anyways.  In this case, it's safe to remove.

Comment: Ok, if OP feels he can handle it then I guess its ok, but I hope OP knows when to create one!

Answer (score 2):

The problem might be due to removing `swap` partition without removing `swap` entry in `/etc/fstab`

If this is the case, then you should remove the `swap` entry from `/etc/fstab` and reboot.

You can do it as suggested by @sudodus in the comment:

- Use the command sudo nano /etc/fstab
- 'comment away' the line pointing to the swap partition. Put a # character in the beginning of that line
- save the file and reboot the computer.

> Note: in most cases, it is recommended to have `swap` partition which
>   will be used when all RAM is in use.

Comment: i did with gparted i did not write a command in terminal

Comment: How can i delete fstab ?

Comment: You need `fstab`. What you should do is remove, or safer: 'comment away' the **line pointing to the swap partition**. Put a # character in the beginning of that line, save the file and reboot the computer. Use the command `sudo nano /etc/fstab` But please consider @Yaron's tip that it is a good idea to have a swap partition, I would add at least a small one, for example 1 GB.